# Can we use '@ContinueNextStepsOnException' to run all the steps in the Karate script instead of karate.match(actual, expected)

Tags: karate

I have a response with hundreds of attributes while matching the attributes the scripts getting failed and further steps are not getting executed. because of this we have to validate the same case multiple times to validate the attribute values. is they a option like @ContinueNextStepsOnException to execute all the steps and it is hard to script using karate.match(actual, expected) for more than 100 attributes I have give actual and expected values if in case of any failure to continue.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option. If your scripts are getting failed - it is because Karate is doing its job correctly !

If you feel you want to skip certain fields, you can easily do so by using `match ... contains` syntax.

I think you are using multiple lines instead of matching the entire JSON in one-line which you can easily do in Karate. For example:

```
* def response = { a: 1, b: 2 }

# not recommended
* match response.a == 1
* match response.b == 2

# recommended
* match response == { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Is it so hard to create the above match, even in development mode ? Just cut and paste valid JSON, and you are done ! I have hardly ever heard users complain about this.